# xcode hanging on startup and attempting loading previously force quit project

Tags: ios, xcode

i had to force quit a project.  Now when I try to open xcode, it attempts unsuccessfully to open that previous project and just hangs.  I cannot open any other projects.  I have tried the following with no success:

restarting computer
re-installing xcode
clearing out Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
clearing out /var/folders/
clearing out

nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was deleting the following folder:

Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState

After this I was able to restart other projects and use xcode.  However the same project was still hanging.

It starting hanging while modifying the storyboard so I only replaced the storyboard file in the project and after that everything works perfectly again.  Of course only the changes to storyboard from when the file was saved will be reflected and this can have very severe effects on your app so I wouldn't suggest doing this unless it was saved just prior to the crash which was the case for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you press the "shift" key when launching Xcode (or most OS X apps really), they launch without reopening any documents.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! After loading xcode, when I selected the same project that was hanging on start up, it opened with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
pod deintegrate
```

remove the xcode workspace file.

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case issue was in last opened file in xCode after system hang up.

I resolved it by deleting of project user settings located in MY_PROJECT.xcworkspace/xcuserdata (a little tip: you need to right-click on MY_PROJECT.xcworkspace and select "Show Package Contents" to access xcuserdata folder in Finder), but I think deletion of xcode saved state as in accepted answer is better option (but I didn't find it in that place).

But xCode was still hanging up on opening that file. May be removing according temp data could help but I didn't find it in 5 minutes, thus I solved it in other way:

1. Made some changes in that file in external editor
2. Opened that file in xCode and made some changes: as result temp unsaved data became fixed and no hanging anymore